# How to run some code in an RxJS chain given there were no errors

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators, rxjs-observables

I am trying to find a way to run some code only if there was no error in a given rxjs chain. Consider the following, is there something like the artificial `NO_ERROR_OCCURED_RUN_HAPPY_PATH_CODE` operator in rxjs?

```js
private wrap(obs: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
  return of(1).pipe(
    tap(() => this.spinner.startSpinner()),
    mergeMap(() =>
      obs.pipe(
        NO_ERROR_OCCURED_RUN_HAPPY_PATH_CODE(() => this.generic_success_popup()),
        catchError(this.handleError),            
      )
    ),
    finalize(() => this.spinner.stopSpinner())
  );
}
```

Comment: `tap` operator is probably what you're looking for

Comment: any operator will run before catchError will run if there is no error

Comment: @FanCheung, if you answer the question I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically almost all operator will be invoke if no error is thrown along the pipe, apart from `finalize`

```
  obs.pipe(
    tap(_=>console.log('no error, will run'),
    // throw some error
    map(_=>throwError('some error'),
    finalize(_=>console.log('will be called when there is error or upon observable complete')),
    tap(_=>console.log('this will not run')),
    catchError(this.handleError),           
  )
```